# Class weights vs under/oversampling

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, imblearn

In imbalanced classification (with scikit-learn) what would be the difference of balancing classes (i.e. set class_weight to balanced) to oversampling with SMOTE for example?
What would be the expected effects of one vs the other?

Comment: I suggest testing both approaches. As always in ML, which of them delivers better results highly depends on your dataset.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Class weights directly modify the loss function by giving more (or less) penalty to the classes with more (or less) weight. In effect, one is basically sacrificing some ability to predict the lower weight class (the majority class for unbalanced datasets) by purposely biasing the model to favor more accurate predictions of the higher weighted class (the minority class).

Oversampling and undersampling methods essentially give more weight to particular classes as well (duplicating observations duplicates the penalty for those particular observations, giving them more influence in the model fit), but due to data splitting that typically takes place in training this will yield slightly different results as well.

Please refer to https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/52627/why-class-weight-is-outperforming-oversampling